# ServiceuBusTrigger read Service Bus connection string from KeyVault

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, nservicebus

I have a simple ServiceBusTrigger which works fine when the connection string is inside my localsettings.json

However, I need to load this from the KeyVault

This approach is easy to do with Web Storage

Has anyone managed to do this with ServiceBusTriggers?

I dont have any pipelines at present

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task PaymentReadyForExport([ServiceBusTrigger("my-topic", "my-subscription", Connection = "event-bus-connection")] string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
    //logic here
}
```

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [Key Vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax) in your App settings for a deployed function app.

Comment: any examples of this would be appreciated. :)